# How to pronounce August Dvorak's last name in English?

Tags: names, technology, computing

I've recently come across the existence of the Dvorak Simplified Keyboard created by professor August Dvorak. And I've been looking for solid sources on how to pronounce the man's name and I can't find any.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) contains both a phonetic guide and a recording of the name being spoken.

Comment: In English phonemes, the unitary Czech phoneme /ř/ is split into a cluster /rʒ/, which forms a syllable boundary in English: /'dvor.ʒak/. This is much like what happens to the unit phoneme /ñ/ in Spanish _cañon_ when it's borrowed as English /'kæn.yən/.

Comment: @John I’ve never heard anyone pronounce it like that. Most people I’ve heard say it like the Wikipedia article suggests, /ˈdvɔːrak/. Personally I’ve always pronounced it as in Czech, /ˈdvor̝aːk/, but I’m pretty sure most people find that terribly pretentious.

Comment: I'm in the UK. I've never heard anything but /dˈvɔːˈʒɑːk/.

Comment: I'm in the Southern/Southwestern US. I've heard different pronunciations for the composer and the keyboard guy.

Comment: I read an interview in _Byte_ magazine about 1992 with John C Dvorak, the nephew of the "keyboard guy". John is an IT writer often mistakenly supposed to have invented the Dvorak Simplified Keyboard (his uncle August did that in 1936). John said "we say 'Divorak' in our family".

Comment: @shoover I'm in Michigan, and my experience is the same as yours. I ordinarily hear the composer's name pronounced in a way tht tries to approximate the Czech pronunciation, while the keyboard guy's name is pronounced with a plain r. I also knew personally knew a man whose last name was Dvorak, and he pronounced it with a plain r.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a comment, Michael Harvey wrote:

> I read an interview in *Byte* magazine about 1992 with John C Dvorak, the nephew of the "keyboard guy". John is an IT writer often mistakenly supposed to have invented the Dvorak Simplified Keyboard (his uncle August did that in 1936). John said "we say 'Divorak' in our family".

Answer (score 1):

I would pronounce it **/d(ə)ˈvɔːrʒɑːk, -ʒæk/** or (spelled another way) **d(ə)-VOR-zha(h)k**.

This is because that is the accepted English pronunciation of the name of the well-known Czech composer [Antonín Leopold Dvořák](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton%C3%ADn_Dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k).

Comment: That's how the composer's name is pronounced in English, but not how the American keyboard-inventor's name is pronounced.

Comment: @Mitch - It's how most people would read the name.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> In English phonemes, the unitary Czech phoneme /ř/ is split into a cluster /rʒ/, which forms a syllable boundary in English: /'dvor.ʒak/. This is much like what happens to the unit phoneme /ñ/ in Spanish *cañon* when it's borrowed as English /'kæn.yən/.